# Import less files within the scope of a mixin

Tags: import, scope, less, less-mixins

Im researching for this a while now, but i cant figure it out.

```
@theme: 'example';

// works
@import (reference) "../themes/@{theme}";

.import(@theme) {
    // doesn't work
    @import (reference) "../themes/@{theme}";
}
```

i guess the mixins get called at the "end" of the compiling process, so it cant import there because it needs the variables earlier.

is there some known hidden secret workaround for this?

this code

```
.import(@theme) {
    // doesn't work
    @import (reference) "../themes/@{theme}";
}
.import(hello);
```

failed because of

> SyntaxError: variable @theme is undefined in less/capsule.less on line 33,

Comment: So what does happen when "it does not work"? Error? Wrong CSS result? Either way make sure you're using Less version that use actually supports importing within mixin using local [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements).

Comment: well, it says variable undefined, and im using the latest grunt-less to compile. I'll post the error messages if i have time

Comment: Latest grunt-contrib-less has Less 2.4.0 or 2.5.0 so this should work just fine.

Comment: well its 2.4.0 but doesent!

Comment: Hmm, you know... actually my mistake, it seems I misinformed you. In v2.x it was enabled for the import statements to use variables defined in other files (before v2.x it was even more limited) but it's still impossible to use local mixin variables (inc. mixin args). So I'm afraid you'll have to use all that `@import (reference) "../themes/***";` explicitly w/o mixins.

Comment: i tried yout stylus, it actually handles some stuff really fluidily. i cropped some functions down to a fifth of their original size. Now im hip || hop if i should switch..

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I think you should make that an answer . "Not possible now" is also an answer :)